# Calling JavaScript from Blazor: how to dispose JavaScript within DotNetObjectReference?

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor-webassembly

I have created a Blazor Webassembly Project and added a key listener in JavaScript, which is listening to every key stroke on the DOM document. **Everything works as expected,** however when I open the Blazor page where the key listener is registered and later open it again, the following error occurs in the Web Browser:

> There is no tracked object with id '2'. Perhaps the
> DotNetObjectReference instance was already disposed. (Parameter
> 'dotNetObjectId')

Obviously the object "dotnethelper" is disposed but the Javascript is still listening / getting called.

Basically I implemented the "Component instance .NET method helper class" from the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-dotnet-from-javascript?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

### Blazor Page:

Note: The IDisposable is injected on the top and the Dispose function is getting called.

```
@code {
    private KeyListenerInvokeHelper _keyListenerInvokeHelper;
    private DotNetObjectReference<KeyListenerInvokeHelper>? objRef;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        objRef = DotNetObjectReference.Create(_keyListenerInvokeHelper);
        await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("initializeKeyListener", objRef);    
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        objRef?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

---

### Javascript File:

```
window.initializeKeyListener = (dotnetHelper) => {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', logKey);
    function logKey(e) {     
        dotnetHelper.invokeMethod('OnKeyDown', e.key);
        console.log('key down ' + e.key);
    }
}
```

---

### KeyListenerInvokeHelper:

```
public class KeyListenerInvokeHelper
{
    private readonly Action<string> action;

    public KeyListenerInvokeHelper(Action<string> action)
    {
        this.action = action;
    }

    [JSInvokable("OnKeyDown")]
    public void OnKeyDown(string key)
    {
        action.Invoke(key);
    }
}
```

### What have I tried so far?

- I tried to reset the function on window.initializeKeyListener (i.e. setting window.initializeKeyListener), however this did not achieve anything
- I tried removing the eventlistener on the 'keydown' event.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74928714/9971404) for related issue and solutions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you dispose of your object, you need to remove the event listener as well. You mentioned `I tried removing the eventlistener on the 'keydown' event.`, but perhaps the way you did it was not correct?
My javascript is a little rusty, but I think you could do something like the following:

```
var logkey;
window.initializeKeyListener = (dotnetHelper) => {
    logkey = (e) => {
        dotnetHelper.invokeMethod('OnKeyDown', e.key);
        console.log('key down ' + e.key);
    };
    document.addEventListener('keydown', logkey);
}

window.removeKeyListener = () => {
    document.removeEventListener('keydown', logkey);
}
```

and then in your component:

```
@implements IAsyncDisposable

public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
{
    await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("removeKeyListener");
    objRef?.Dispose();
}
```

Having said that, perhaps calling a static method in C# using `[JSInvokable]` would be better suited for your use case?

Comment: This is very good, and I added [a request](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/27536) for them to add it to the docs.

Comment: mind, for BLAZOR SERVER this suffers from the following issue:
when reloading the page (or simply click home button to go to blank) this will cause a `Microsoft.JSInterop.JSDisconnectedException: 'JavaScript interop calls cannot be issued at this time. This is because the circuit has disconnected and is being disposed.'`
see:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72488563/blazor-server-side-application-throwing-system-invalidoperationexception-javas

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/33336